# why focus on input box and options does not work with bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, draggable

I added a draggable directive to my modal window using twitter bootstrap , it has a problem that input textboxes and select cannot be focused/accessed.

**Index.Html**

```
   <div  class=" bg-white" modaldraggable>
        <form name="_form" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit(_form)">
               <div class="modal-header">
                 <h3>Chart Settings</h3>
              </div>
               <div  class="modal-body" >
               <input name="inptxt">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">    
              <button ng-click="dismiss()"  class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit"   class="btn btn-default" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Save</button>
              </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**App.Js:**

```
routerApp.directive('modaldraggable', function ($document) {
  "use strict";
  return function (scope, element) {
    var startX = 0,
      startY = 0,
      x = 0,
      y = 0;
     element= angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-dialog"));
     console.log("added directive");
      // element.css({
      //  position: 'fixed',
      //   cursor: 'move'
      // });

    element.on('mousedown', function (event) {
      // Prevent default dragging of selected content
      event.preventDefault();
      startX = event.screenX - x;
      startY = event.screenY - y;
      $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
    });

    function mousemove(event) {
      y = event.screenY - startY;
      x = event.screenX - startX;
      element.css({
        top: y + 'px',
        left: x + 'px'
      });
    }

    function mouseup() {
      $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the plunker,

http://plnkr.co/edit/naVFDnnezpyW65DxYu4N

Comment: I dont find any inputs in it

Comment: please refresh, i made the changes now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way jquery ui defines draggable http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4945

Similar thing you have done with your draggable directive. You have set event.preventDefault(), which will disable the text selection but will also impact the inputs inside the draggable modal.

The solution would **not be** to remove **e.prevent** default as it will again enable the **textselection** , which looks weird while dragging the element(try dragging the modal while mouse on text CHART SETTINGS).

**work around**:  You can define a handle to the modal, using which you shall drag the modal. For example you can drag the modal only if the mouse pointer is at the modal-header.. this would not enable the text selection.

Comment: You do realise that you just repeated what I said, right? Last sentence of my answer is: "But I still think you should have a draggable area instead of making the whole thing draggable"

Comment: @DinuSorin. Yes i do realize but wanted to tell why it should not be done instead of what you answered

Comment: @NaeemShaikh how can i do that?

Comment: This fix helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
element.on('mousedown', function (event) {
  // Prevent default dragging of selected content
  **event.preventDefault();**
  startX = event.screenX - x;
  startY = event.screenY - y;
  $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
  $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
});
```

you prevent the default action to happen (in your case, focus on input) You should never have a panel that you can drag from anywhere and that it has content in it. You should have a drag zone (like a title).

Here's the code with prevent default commented out: http://plnkr.co/edit/3cpq4vQADP1snHhBMLIj?p=info

But I still think you should have a draggable area instead of making the whole thing draggable

Comment: This enables text selection.. try to drag the modal while mouse on the text(on CHART SETTINGS).. see how it looks..

Comment: @NaeemShaikh i dont see any problem. do you have idea, the modal getting closed when clicking on any button?

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the directory to allow for dragging only on the modal header title section. In addition, it allows you to type into your form inputs okay.

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('modalMovable', ['$document',
    function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            var startX = 0,
                startY = 0,
                x = 0,
                y = 0;

            dialogWrapper = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content"));

            dialogWrapper.css({
                position: 'relative'
            });

            dialogWrapper.on('mousedown', function (event) {
                if (event.target.classList.contains('modal-header') == false && event.target.classList.contains('modal-title') == false) {
                    return true;
                }
                startX = event.pageX - x;
                startY = event.pageY - y;
                $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
            });

            function mousemove(event) {
                y = event.pageY - startY;
                x = event.pageX - startX;
                dialogWrapper.css({
                    top: y + 'px',
                    left: x + 'px'
                });
            }

            function mouseup() {
                $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
            }
        }
    };
}
]);
```

Then add

```
<div class="modal-header" modal-movable>
    <h4 class="modal-title">some title</h4>
</div>
```